# Deploying react app to amazon s3 via github actions

Tags: reactjs, github, amazon-s3

So i have a Ionic React app which i would want that every time i push to the master branch it automatically uploads the files to amazons s3 bucket as well. I have come pretty far and my only problem is with the yml file in which i have to specifiy the directory to be uploaded. This is how it looks now:

name: Deploy

on:

push:
branches: [ master ]

workflow_dispatch:

jobs:

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest


steps:

  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
    with: 
      node-version: 12
  - run: npm install -g npm
  - run: npm ci
  - run: npm build
  - uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
    with:
      aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      aws-region: eu-north-1
  - run: aws s3 sync <What to insert here?> s3://example-bucket
```

Now i have tried with putting jsut an . there but it uploaded for 20 mins without reaching an end and it was not with a strcutured folders in the s3 buckets but every file for itself. Any solutions? I feel like it is a easy task but im no backend developer

I have the index file here: payeat-s3/public/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I have used this YAML configuration to deploy my react site to S3 using Github Actions:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop

name: Build and Deploy Site to S3

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: Setup Node
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: '12.x'
    - name: Build App
      run: |
       yarn && yarn build && ls *
      env:
        CI: "" 
    - name: Copy to S3
      uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
      with:
        args: --acl public-read --follow-symlinks --delete
      env:
        AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.AWS_S3_BUCKET }}
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        AWS_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
        SOURCE_DIR: ${{ secrets.SOURCE_DIR }}
```

I have added more details in this blog - https://blog.coderise.io/deploy-react-app-aws-s3-using-github-actions/

Comment: I want to only upload build contents which is created by npm run build, instead, it pushes everything to the repo and when specified build it couldn't find it, can you please tell me how should i do it?